# Qt: wrapping Q_OBJECT declaration in #ifndef directive

Tags: qt, signals-slots, preprocessor-directive

I think that

```
#ifndef SERVER
    Q_OBJECT
#endif
```

is causing

> Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.

from my compiler. Probably because whatever Qt preprocessor is looking for `Q_OBJECT` is not affected by (or not properly affected by) the C preprocessor directive. What's the proper way to deal with this?

I'm doing this because I don't need the signal-slot jazz on the server, so for the sake of efficiency, I eliminate that declaration.

I'm running Qt 4.8 building in GNU on Ubuntu 64-bit.

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimizations. There is no computational overhead on the runtime, just a tiny memory overhead for the metadata. The savings are not worth the potential trouble you might run into by not using Qt as intended. It's bad enough when you use it as intended ;) don't make it worse.

Comment: @dtech Is this "memory overhead" of which you speak compile-time or runtime?

Comment: Asking such questions is a clear indication you don't know what you are doing. In such cases, it is always best to not do it ;)

Comment: @Opux, What is SERVER? is it an object of Class ? its not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Opux, is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677037/c-macro-if-class-if-defined

Comment: @MohammadKanan "SERVER" is just a macro that is defined for a particular build profile. I just want the code to compile for the server as if it didn't have that Q_OBJECT. The other projects (called "client" and "daemon") need it.
Unfortunately, that link you provided only seems useful for running Visual. I'm doing this in GNU.

Comment: This message is produced by `moc`. If you want to avoid it, maybe don't run moc at all? But anyway, I don't see any reason doing this (apart from saving some compile time)...

Comment: @Opus, I am not sure if preprocessor can run Q_OBJECT macro. but the scenario you described can be solved by Abstract class from which client and daemon are derived .. if you have implemented virtual c++ methods then you know Abstract classes

Comment: @Jaa-c Not sure if I can avoid building `moc`. If its only effect is compile-time, then I don't see the point either. I'm more interested in its run-time effect, but that answer is proving to be elusive

Comment: @Opux: What exactly are you interest in? Q_OBJECT macro adds a few virtual methods to every QObject and also a member, so there is some memory allocation, but no more runtime overhead... But if you don't use QObject properties other than signal slots meschanism, I wouldn't worry...

Comment: @Opux I don't see a case where your object could be a `QObject` for one project compilation and not a QObject for another one. This should be 2 different classes in my opinion, can you have a generic data-class (for server) and a QObject-class that is composed of the data-class ?

Comment: @ymoreau In one project I'm using signal/slots and in another I'm not. In any case, I've lost interest in this picking this particular nit. I just pay it safe and leave the declaration in both

Comment: @Opux sure I get that, but if you don't need signal/slots you probably don't need `QObject`s at all, probably don't need to inherit and use `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @ymoreau But I *do* need signal/slots, just not in both projects. Maybe there's a better solution that could have been used if I was starting from scratch, but I'm afraid I'm hamstrung by over 10 years of development that preceded me signing on to it

Comment: @Opux back to my 1st message then, you *do not need* signal/slots in both projects so you probably do not need the same classes/code/inheritance-design in both projects. But if you have other constraints or that it's too late, don't bother too much because there is too few to gain indeed.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand, server and client compilation is done in same top level project and might coexist. if you want client to use Q_OBJECT macro while server not, then this code is C++ polymorphism realization of such requirement while having same class name for both (top_server):

Here all instances (Server, client ...etc.) are instantiated from top_Server ..

What matters is that server class never call Q_OBJECT macro while client class does implement the Q_OBJECT macro.

Top abstract class code:

abstract_class.h

```
#ifndef ABSTRACT_CLASS_H
#define ABSTRACT_CLASS_H
#include <QString>
class top_Server // Abstract Class
{
public:
    virtual bool method1 (QString,QString) =0;
};
#endif // ABSTRACT_CLASS_H
```

Then SERVER derived class declaration

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
#include "abstract_class.h"
#include <QObject>

class Server: public top_Server
{

public:
    explicit Server (QString ,QString, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool method1 (QString,QString);
};
#endif // SERVER_H
```

Then Client derived Class declaration

client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H
#include <QObject>
#include "abstract_class.h"
class client: public QObject, public top_Server // Client class inherits Abstract class and runs the Q_OBJECT macro
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit client(QString ,QString, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool method1 (QString,QString);
};
#endif // CLIENT_H
```

Then class code in .CPP files

```
client::client(QString DB_user, QString DB_pwd, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
bool client::method1(QString str1, QString str2)
{

}

Server::Server (QString str1 ,QString str2 , QObject *parent)
{

}
bool Server::method1(QString str1, QString str2)
{

}
```

Now the implementation of Server and client is hidden and the same class name can be used to instantiate any, you also can switch from one object to another:

```
 top_Server *common_object_name;
```

then somewhere a client can be used:

```
common_object_name = new client;
```

....
and somewhere else a server

```
common_object_name = new server;
```

the cost is know of having two hidden classes while the advantage is obvious!

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry I cannot comment yet, so I answer instead.)

I'd suggest @Mohammad Kanan's way, if possible in your case.

Otherwise, though, Qt's moc defines `Q_MOC_RUN` when it parses your code. That way, using `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN [...] #endif`, you can exclude code portions from being processed by the moc entirely. (Reference: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html#command-line-options)